# How do I create a Storable instance for this type?

Tags: haskell, binding, ffi

Suppose I have the following C structure:

```
typedef struct _Ready {
    int ready;
} *Ready;
```

I represent it in Haskell using this type:

```
data Ready = Ready { ready :: CInt }
```

Now I want a `Storable` instance. The following works fine:

```
instance Storable Ready where
    alignment = sizeOf
    sizeOf _  = (#size Ready)
```

However, adding any of these definitions of `peek` and `poke` fails:

```
    peek p = Ready <$> (#peek Ready, ready) p   -- FAILS
    poke p (Ready r) = (#poke Ready, ready) p r -- FAILS
```

The error boils down to `ready` not being part of a structure or union:

```
/usr/lib/ghc-7.10.1/template-hsc.h:72:24:
  error: request for member ‘ready’ in something not a structure or union
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ready` (the C type) is not a struct or a union, it's a pointer to a `struct _Ready`. You should use `struct _Ready` instead, like

```
peek p = Ready <$> (#peek struct _Ready, ready) p
poke p (Ready r) = (#poke struct _Ready, ready) p r
```

Also, your `sizeOf` method is wrong and needs the same change. You need the size of the struct, but you currently have the size of a pointer to the struct, and they are usually not the same on a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly tell what you're doing wrong because I've never stumbled upon all the hash signs you are using. But the following should do the trick:

```
instance Storable Ready where
    alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: CInt)
    sizeOf _ = sizeOf (undefined :: CInt)
    peek p = Ready <$> peekByteOff p 0
    poke p (Ready r) = pokeByteOff p 0 r
```

The `0` parameter to `peekByteOff` and `pokeByteOff` just reflects that the `ready` component of the `_Ready` type (in C) is the first field of the record. I'm not very sure about defining `alignment` and `sizeOf`, but I wanted you to show an alternative possibility nevertheless.